# ggplot2 - missing some x-labes and grid lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a number of data sets using ggplot2 in R. To make the plots easier to compare, I am setting the limits of the y-scale, but, it turns out, nothing is plotted above the 'natural top' of the plot.

eg for this plot: 
[image: Plot with missing labels and lines]
<sub>(source: [sickel.net](http://sickel.net/misc/output.png))</sub>

I have tried to set the top y-value to 500 (and looking at the white space at the top, I have managed to) but how to make ggplot also plot the labels for 400,450 and 500 and the corresponding grid lines?

the data are in the dataframe df with df$dataset and df$error as data and error-level respectively. My plotting code presently is

```
max = max(df$dataset + df$error) * 1.05
if(max > 300) max=505

dataplot = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=species,y=dataset,fill=dim,ylim=c(0,max)))
dataplot = dataplot+geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
dataplot = dataplot+scale_fill_manual(values=c("#BBBBBB", "#444444"))
dataplot = dataplot + ylab(ylab) + xlab(xlab) + opts(legend.title=theme_blank())

limits <- aes(ymax = df$dataset+df$error, ymin=df$dataset-df$error)
dodge = position_dodge(width=0.9)

dataplot = dataplot + geom_errorbar(limits, position=dodge, width=0.5) 
dataplot = dataplot + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white', colour='white'))
dataplot = dataplot + opts(panel.grid.major = theme_line(colour = "gray"))

# dataplot = dataplot + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, max))
# dataplot = dataplot + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max))

dataplot = dataplot + 
               opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(colour = "black",angle=90),
                    axis.text.y = theme_text(colour = "black"))
dataplot = dataplot + opts(legend.key.size = unit(0.3, "cm"))
print(dataplot)
```

As can be seen from the commented out lines, I have tried coord_cartesian, scale_y_continous as well as the present y-lim without any luck (yes, and I know that coord_cartesian is zooming in)

Comment: Does `dataplot + ylim(0, max)` do what you want?

Comment: Sorry about the unrelated response, but couldn't find a contact email.  From one Clef to another (see my logo): what's your instrument of choice?

Comment: I can tell you for sure that your use of `ylim` inside of `aes` will not do what you want (and will not do anything useful, ever). But it would help, I think, if you could provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That's OK ;-) I'm playing electrical bass, fretted or fretless, wanting to learn to play double bass.. Your clef looks like you're a viola player? (Hmm, I have an e-mail in my profile, seems that it's not visible)

Comment: @MortenSickel No- cello.  The viola's alto clef is pointed one line lower down :-) .  I do a little electric bass on the side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the ylimits you can add:

```
+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,500))
```

In order to set the tick points, you can use:

```
breaks=seq(0, 500, 50) # which means ticks from 0-500, every 50 units
```

Therefore, I think you need to add the code below to your plot code:

```
+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,500),breaks=seq(0, 500, 50))
```

Comment: I will be curious what the OP says about this answer, given that their question specifically refers to having tried setting `scale_y_continuous(limits = ...)` and that it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Joran...I respect your opinion but I don't agree with you. I refer you to this sentence in the question: "...how to make ggplot also plot the labels for 400,450 and 500 and the corresponding grid lines?..."

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my comment. It was not meant to suggest that you were wrong, or that you should delete your answer. My point was that it is very unclear what is going on with the OP's code, because it is not reproducible, so it is impossible to tell if this answer will be helpful. It may very well be, who knows. If the OP _has_ in fact tried `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,500))` which they _explicitly_ say they have tried, then their plot would extend well above what is currently shown in the question.

Comment: Sorry for misinterpretation...Best, -Sepehr

Comment: I had tried those two commented out lines, with the same result. Adding the breaks, did fix it. According to one of the other answers, it seems that that should not have been needed, so something strange is going on somewhere, but I'll check that out later, has a paper to submit today ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For me, using either `ylim(0, max)` or `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max),breaks=seq(0, max, 50))` works the way I think you want. For example, using the `diamonds` data:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
(p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position="dodge"))
max.y <- 10000 
p + ylim(0, max.y)
p + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max.y), breaks=seq(0, max.y, 1000))
```

I get the following three plots. The first one is without setting the y-axis, the second uses `ylim()`, and the third uses `scale_y_continuous()`. I hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: You're right, that's exactly what I wanted. I must have messed up something somewhere. Thanks.